# With Zabbix API, how do I get the values of items/resources rather than just the ID's?

Tags: ruby, monitoring, zabbix

I have some data in a Custom Screen in Zabbix, and would like to pull the data from the screen via the API. I'm using this Ruby gem: https://github.com/express42/zabbixapi

I'm able to successfully connect and query, but the results I'm getting are not very useful:

```
p zbx.query(
    :method => "item.get",
    :params => {
      :itemids => "66666",
      :output => "extend"
    }
  )

# [{"itemid"=>"66666", "type"=>"0", "snmp_community"=>"", "snmp_oid"=>"", "hostid"=>"77777", "name"=>"Fro Packages", "key_"=>"system.sw.packages[davekey1|davekey2|davekey3|davekey4]", "delay"=>"300", "history"=>"90", "trends"=>"365", "status"=>"0", "value_type"=>"1", "trapper_hosts"=>"", "units"=>"", "multiplier"=>"0", "delta"=>"0", "snmpv3_securityname"=>"", "snmpv3_securitylevel"=>"0", "snmpv3_authpassphrase"=>"", "snmpv3_privpassphrase"=>"", "formula"=>"1", "error"=>"", "lastlogsize"=>"0", "logtimefmt"=>"", "templateid"=>"88888", "valuemapid"=>"0", "delay_flex"=>"", "params"=>"", "ipmi_sensor"=>"", "data_type"=>"0", "authtype"=>"0", "username"=>"", "password"=>"", "publickey"=>"", "privatekey"=>"", "mtime"=>"0", "flags"=>"0", "filter"=>"", "interfaceid"=>"25", "port"=>"", "description"=>"", "inventory_link"=>"0", "lifetime"=>"30", "snmpv3_authprotocol"=>"0", "snmpv3_privprotocol"=>"0", "state"=>"0", "snmpv3_contextname"=>""}]
```

You can see that it's returning a bunch of ID's for the items, including the correct keys, but I can't seem to get the actual plain text *values*, which is the data I'm interested in.

I started with the screen_id, then got the screenitem_id, now the item_id, but I don't seem to be getting any closer to what I want!

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Getting items or getting hosts means getting their description, not the data. is You are after [history](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/history/get). Reading the actual Zabbix user manual and API docs is highly recommended.